# Resolving Dual-Boot Issue: Windows Not Showing in GRUB Menu

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader, troubleshooting

I recently encountered a dual-boot issue on my Debian 12 system where Windows 10 was not showing up in the GRUB menu after a Debian update. I spent some time troubleshooting the problem and was able to resolve it. I wanted to share my experience in case others encounter a similar issue.

**Issue Description**:
After a Debian update, my GRUB bootloader stopped showing the option to boot into Windows 10. Initially, I believed my Windows partition was located at /dev/sda2, but it turned out to be at /dev/sda1.

Comment: Your question should only be a question. You should separate the answer you included in your question and put it in an answer to your own question, as encouraged in this help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer .

Answer (score 5):

For me I also encounter this problem recently when I upgrade my `grub2` package from version `2.06-13` to `2.06-13+deb12u1`. The solution is to uncomment this line in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` to let GRUB scan for Windows 10. This way I do not need to manually add an entry in `/etc/grub.d/`.

Note: this update is possibly related to a recent security update: https://www.debian.org/security/2022/dsa-5280

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

1. Verify the Windows Partition: To confirm the location of your Windows partition, you can use commands like `lsblk` or `fdisk -l`. In my case, it was /dev/sda1.
2. Update the Custom GRUB Entry: I added a custom GRUB menu entry for Windows in the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file. Here's what it looked like:

```bash
menuentry "Windows 10" {
    insmod ntfs
    set root=(hd0,1)  # Modify this to match your Windows partition
    chainloader +1
}
```

Make sure to replace `(hd0,1)` with the appropriate partition information for your Windows installation.

3. Enable `os-prober`: In the `/etc/default/grub` file, ensure that the `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER` setting is set to `false` to enable automatic detection of other bootable partitions.
4. Update GRUB: Run `sudo update-grub` to regenerate the GRUB configuration.

After following these steps, my GRUB menu displayed the "Windows 10" option, allowing me to boot into Windows 10 successfully.

**Conclusion**:
If you encounter a similar issue where Windows doesn't show up in the GRUB menu, consider checking the Windows partition location, configuring a custom GRUB entry, and enabling `os-prober`. This should help you resolve the problem and restore dual-boot functionality.

I hope this post helps others who may face the same issue, and please feel free to ask if you have any questions or need further assistance.

Comment: Windows in BIOS mode, normally has two NTFS partitions, boot & main install. Most users do not know about boot partition as not normally shown. With UEFI installs both Windows & Linux use same ESP - efi system partition which is FAT32. With UEFI the chain entry to ESP partition is ` chainloader /EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi`